# The Joel Test como funciona?

Tags: engenharia-de-software

Me deparei com a seguinte frase abaixo.

> "Conseguimos 11/12 pontos no “The Joel Test”, que mede a qualidade do
>   desenvolvimento de software dentro da nossa empresa. "

O que se trata? Como funciona o The Joel Test? Ele é realmente um medidor de qualidade de software?

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## O que é

[Esse é o Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) ([Em português](http://brazil.joelonsoftware.com/Articles/TheJoelTest.html)).

Ele não mede qualidade do software, embora alguns acreditam que sim. Na verdade alguns acreditam que é possível quantificar qualidade do software, quando na verdade dá apenas para quantificar alguns critérios sobre defeitos. O teste nem cai nesse erro, e é muito simples. Basicamente as respostas são "sim" ou "não" para 12 itens.

- Você usa controle de código?
- Você pode compilar em somente um passo?
- Você faz compilações diárias?
- Você tem uma base de dados de *bugs*?
- Você corrige os *bugs* antes de escrever código novo?
- Você tem um cronograma atualizado?
- Você tem uma especificação?
- Os programadores tem condições de trabalho tranquilas?
- Você usa as melhores ferramentas que o dinheiro pode comprar?
- Você tem testadores?
- Novos candidatos escrevem código durante a entrevista?
- Você faz testes de usabilidade de corredor?

Olhando os itens vemos que ele dá um indicativo de maturidade da equipe na adoção de algumas técnicas e metodologias que o Joel acredita serem importantes.

Qualquer pessoa pouco ingênua percebe que pode adotar tudo isso e produzir softwares completamente deficientes. Na verdade isso vale para a adoção de qualquer metodologia. É o que eu sempre digo: fazer certo é o que importa.

É claro que é interessante ter alguns parâmetros. Listas como essa ajudam pensar sobre o assunto, mas tem que saber quando seguir ou não.

Como ideia geral são excelentes recomendações, mas tem caso que ficar abaixo dos 12 é a melhor coisa que você pode fazer. Tentar "passar no teste" a todo custo é bobagem.

## Motivação do teste

Entenda que o Joel começou o blog dele muito para divulgar sua empresa que produz ferramentas para desenvolvedores. Muito do que ele fala faz muito sentido, afinal ele é um desenvolvedor experiente tendo trabalhado no que provavelmente é o melhor software da Microsoft (ou era até começarem estragar). Mas ele tem um objetivo próprio com o blog, não perca isso de vista. Dito isto, recomendo a leitura de quase todos artigos que ele publicou. Ele tem um interesse genuíno de melhorar a qualidade dos desenvolvedores.

O teste ajuda também vender a empresa dele como um local agradável de se trabalhar. Um dos objetivos do blog sempre foi atrair os melhores talentos para a empresa dele. O que mostra a qualidade de empreendedor dele, ele sabe que não pode produzir bons resultados com desenvolvedores medíocres. Pra conquistar as melhores cabeças, precisa oferecer o que outros não oferecem e precisa fazer todo mundo saber disso.

Então muito provavelmente a frase citada na pergunta vem de alguém que está fazendo a mesma coisa, querem te vender que lá é um bom lugar pra trabalhar. Assim eles recebem milhares de currículos e podem selecionar os melhores.

## Não leve o teste tão a sério

Há quem discorde dele. Tem gente que acha que faltam coisas mais importantes e tem gente que acha que tem coisas que não dizem muito para a qualidade direta do ambiente do desenvolvimento. No fundo cada um pode estudar o assunto e fazer sua própria lista. Tem algumas variações por aí (procure em inglês por *updated*). [Opinião do próprio autor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109363/140010).

Quem usa o [Stack Overflow Jobs](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) (agora defunto) sabe que os anunciantes são incentivados a responder o Joel Test, então ele virou mais um instrumento de marketing.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ele é um desenvolvedor experiente tendo trabalhado no que provavelmente era o melhor software da Microsoft até inventarem aquela porcaria de ribbon. :P